# Why can't I append 2 lists then save as a varible then print in python?

Tags: python

I'm new to python, still learning basic commands and stuff. I am now on making and editing lists, and I am trying to sort 2 lists alphabetically then append them, finally printing them. I have written the following code:

```
songs = ["Stairway to Heaven", "All Along the Watchtower", "Riders on the Storm"]

artists = ["Deep Purple", "Wu-Tang", "Protoje", "RTJ", "The Doors", "Jimi Hendrix", "Led Zepplin"]

songs.sort()

artists.sort()

test = [songs.append(artists)]

print(test)
```

I've also tried

```
songs = ["Stairway to Heaven", "All Along the Watchtower", "Riders on the Storm"]

artists = ["Deep Purple", "Wu-Tang", "Protoje", "RTJ", "The Doors", "Jimi Hendrix", "Led Zepplin"]

test = [songs.append(artists)]

test.sort()

print(test)
```

Both results in [None] but what I want is to append the 2 lists, sort them alphabetically, then print the result. It isn't for anything important, just trying to get familiar with python.

Comment: The list `.append()` method does not return the new list; it returns `None`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine them first and just sort once:

```
songs = ["Stairway to Heaven", "All Along the Watchtower", "Riders on the Storm"]

artists = ["Deep Purple", "Wu-Tang", "Protoje", "RTJ", "The Doors", "Jimi Hendrix", "Led Zepplin"]

test = sorted(songs + artists)

print(test)
```

Or sort them first and then combine:

```
songs = ["Stairway to Heaven", "All Along the Watchtower", "Riders on the Storm"]

artists = ["Deep Purple", "Wu-Tang", "Protoje", "RTJ", "The Doors", "Jimi Hendrix", "Led Zepplin"]

test = sorted(songs) + sorted(artists)

print(test)
```

You will have 2 different outcomes.

Comment: If it worked, please upvote the answer and accept as correct. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To append two lists together, you need to do this:

```
test = songs + artists
```

Because this line:

```
[songs.append(artists)]
```

Is adding the whole `artists` list as a single element at the end of the `songs` list, and besides `append()` returns `None`, so you'll simply end up with a list that looks like this:

```
[None]
```

Please spend some time reading the documentation, to understand the difference between appending *to* a list and concatenating *two* lists, and remember to check exactly what value is returned by an operation - to avoid surprises with `append()`, `sort()` and others that return `None`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because where you're doing

```
test = [songs.append(artists)]
```

you're doing an append. Change it to append before and then do

```
songs.append(artists)
test = [songs]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append two lists together with the `+` operator. Using `sorted()` returns a new list sorted from the elements given.

`Sorted(list1 + list2)` gives you a new sorted list of all of the elements.

```
songs = ["Stairway to Heaven", "All Along the Watchtower", "Riders on the Storm"]
artists = ["Deep Purple", "Wu-Tang", "Protoje", "RTJ", "The Doors", "Jimi Hendrix", "Led Zepplin"]
combined = sorted(songs+artists)
>>> combined
['All Along the Watchtower', 'Deep Purple', 'Jimi Hendrix', 'Led Zepplin', 'Protoje', 'RTJ', 'Riders on the Storm', 'Stairway to Heaven', 'The Doors', 'Wu-Tang']
```